# How write declaration for class and namespace with same name in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using a 3rd party Javascript library in this format:

```
var MyClass = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

MyClass.prototype.greet = function () {
    window.alert('Hello ' + this.name)
}
```

I want to write a Typescript declaration for this. I've got this sort of thing:

```
declare class MyClass {
    constructor(name: string);
    greet(): void;
}
```

This is all compiling fine and when I just want to refer to the types it is working as expected. But I'm having problems trying to use the class implementation.

Using it this way, it compiles and runs, but I get no compile time checking

```
const MyClass = (require('./MyClass') as any).MyClass;
const a = new MyClass('Bob'); //a is any
```

Using it this way I get a compiler error

```
const MyClass = (require('./MyClass') as any).MyClass as MyClass;
const a = new MyClass('Bob'); //Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

Using it this way I get a compiler error

```
import './MyClass';
const a = new MyClass('Bob');
//duplicate identifier in MyClass.d.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
declare class MyClass {
    greet(): void;
}

declare type MyClassFactory = (x: string) => MyClass

const factory = (require('./MyClass') as any).MyClass as MyClassFactory;
const a = factory('Bob');
```

which is to detach the class and its constructor function

Comment: Thanks for this - I modified this a bit to give `declare type MyClassFactory = new (x: string) => MyClass` and `const a = new factory('Bob');`

Answer (score 2):

So the first problem is that your declaration file is for the MyClass module and defines the class but doesn't describe that modules exports.
The second problem is that you then need the matching import statement in your main module. `import './MyClass'` is only to import side effects (see [the typescript modules doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Based on the code that works, it looks like the MyClass module exports an object with a MyClass property (set to the MyClass class) so that's what I've added to your declaration file.

The `MyClass.d.ts` declaration file for the js module:

```
declare class MyClass {
  constructor(name: string);
  greet(): void;
}

export { MyClass }
```

Then in your `main.ts`:

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

let a = new MyClass('foo');
a.greet();
```

Comment: when I was migrating to webpack with TS codebase this was very helpful for me - to add `export` everywhere.